# Polynomial Equation Solution

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Use Demoivre's theorem to show:
$cos 7θ = 64 cos7 θ − 112 cos5 θ + 56 cos3 θ − 7 cos θ$

Hence,solve:
$128x^7 −224x^5 +112x^3 −14x+1=0$

I've shown the first part and multiplied the equation by 2 and added 1 to it which gives me cos7θ = -0.5 . This is very simple but i'm confused about which angles should i take into account? can someone please explain.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

As you started, you can solve $$2\cos 7\theta+1=0$$
$$\cos 7\theta=-1/2$$
$$7\theta=\pm \frac{2\pi}{3}+2k\pi;~~k~\text{is an integer}$$
$$\theta=\pm \frac{2\pi}{21}+\frac{2k\pi}{7}$$
To satisfy two equations with trigonometric form and function of $x$; there should be $\theta$ value(s) which satisfies $\cos \theta=x.$

Let get $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{21}$ (when $k=0$), then $x=\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)$. This can be substituted to the function with $x$ as
$$128 \cos ^7\left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)-224 \cos ^5\left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)+112 \cos ^3\left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)-14 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)+1=0$$ Since equation is satisfied, thus $$x=\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)$$ is a solution.

Similarly, we have 7 distinct roots at $$x=\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{7}+\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)~~\text{when}~~k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6.$$

If we evaluate them numerically, we may get $\{x= -0.988831\},\{x= -0.733052\},\{x= -0.5\},\{x= 0.0747301\},\{x= 0.365341\},\{x= 0.826239\},\{x= 0.955573\}.$

Hope this will help you, however, there may be alternative ways for the analysis !!!

Comment: thank you for your response. I actually wanted to know how many solutions can there be for X^7 equation? the first 7 multiples?

Comment: There may be 7 roots (distinct) as we can see that $2\pi/7$.

Comment: my answers are coming out to be:

$cos(\frac{2k\pi}{21}) where   k = 2,4,8,10,14,16$

Are these distinct roots?

Comment: Pls check the edited answer.

Comment: just one thing, why did you not use $- 2π/21$ ?

Comment: $\pm$ comes from the general solution for $\cos$ equation. You may find some time that you get same answer for either + or -. E.g., $\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}+\frac{2\ 5 \pi }{7}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{2\ 2 \pi }{7}-\frac{1}{21} (2 \pi )\right)=0.0747301$

Comment: oh thank you so mcuh!